# Why does the UI label not delete when deleting it via removeUI inside of this for loop?

Tags: r, shiny

EDIT at bottom...

ORIGINAL:
I had thought I understood this (e.g. [Why is removeUI leaving behind the UI label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71211747/why-is-removeui-leaving-behind-the-ui-label)) but I can't figure out why it isn't working here. I have a working MRE that does work as intended for a slightly different use, but it isn't for this one and I can't see a difference.

As part of a larger app, I have a UI element that lists the names of all the columns of data. As background, this part is for discrete gauge analysis where assessors categorize a set of samples, perhaps as "good" or "bad." Often the user will just have a single observation of all the samples for each assessor, but sometimes they may have an assessor categorize the samples multiple times. This allows a check on internal consistency.

The first dropdown UI lists all the column names and has the user select the assessors. When they have repeated measures, the columns might be labeled with the name of the assessor and a number to indicate how many repeated measures they did, for example, Mary, Mary2, Mary3. So for the first dropdown, they might select Mary.

Once the user selects the "Mary" column, if they are going to do a check of internal consistency, they would check the box, then have another UI appear with the remaining unselected columns so they can select Mary2 and Mary3 which are the repeated measures for that assessor.

There may be one or more assessors, so going back and selecting John in the first dropdown should then add a new dropdown UI for John so we can tell it that Jon2 and John3 are John's repeated measures.

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the code below delete the label? I mean for it to look at how many assessors are selected in the first UI, delete any existing UI elements, then add a drop-down list for each one selected that shows the remaining unselected columns. Each would have the inputID of d_assessor_1, d_assessor2, etc.
2. When the UI gets added, even though I am using "afterEnd" it is adding the UI after the label, not after the box itself.

```
library(shiny)

assessors<-c("John"=1,"John2"=2,"John3"=3,"John4"=4,"Mary"=5,"Mary2"=6,"Mary3"=7,"Mary4"=8,"Phred"=9,"Phred2"=10,"Phred3"=11,"Phred4"=12,"Becky"=13,"Becky2"=14,"Becky3"=15,"Becky4"=16)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = "msa_d_UI1",
                      label = "Select Appraisers",
                      multiple=T,
                      choices = assessors),
          checkboxInput(inputId = "msa_d_internal",label = "Internal Consistency?",value = FALSE),
          div(id="d_assessor0"),
        ),

        
        mainPanel(
           # Nothing to see here
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(c(input$msa_d_UI1,input$msa_d_internal), {
    UI1<-as.numeric(input$msa_d_UI1)
    do_internal<-input$msa_d_internal
    req(UI1,do_internal)
    choices<-assessors
    
    #take out those already selected
    fact_selected<-UI1
    temp<-seq(1:length(choices))
    temp<-temp[-fact_selected]
    choices<-choices[temp]
    sel_apps_names<-names(assessors)[UI1]
    
    num<-length(UI1)    
    
    adds<-seq(1,num)
    for (i in adds){
      #first remove current UI
      removeUI(selector = paste0("div:has(> #d_assessor",i,")"),immediate = TRUE)#this doesn't remove the label
      #add new UI
      here<-paste0("#d_assessor",i-1)
      insertUI(
        selector=here,
        where="afterEnd",
        ui=selectInput(inputId = paste0("d_assessor",i),
                       label = paste0("Select Repeated Measures for ",sel_apps_names[i]),
                       multiple=T,
                       choices = choices),
        immediate = TRUE
      )
    }
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT:
I implemented @Jan's idea and fixed some other things in the script that were bugs. The problem is that now it stopped generating the -label he used to target the full div for some reason. Here is what the div looks like now before deletion:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container"><!--This is the div I now want to delete -->
  <label class="control-label" for="d_assessor4">Select Repeated Measures for Rick</label>
  <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick form-control bs3"><select data-actions-box="true" id="d_assessor4" class="selectpicker form-control shiny-bound-input" multiple="multiple"><option value="2">Terry2</option>
<option value="3">Terry3</option>
<option value="5">Rick2</option>
<option value="6">Rick3</option>
<option value="8">Larry2</option>
<option value="9">Larry3</option>
<option value="10">Actual</option></select><button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default bs-placeholder" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-25" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" data-id="d_assessor4" title="Nothing selected"><div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Nothing selected</div></div> </div><span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open"><div class="bs-actionsbox"><div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-block"><button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-select-all btn btn-default">Select All</button><button type="button" class="actions-btn bs-deselect-all btn btn-default">Deselect All</button></div></div><div class="inner open" role="listbox" id="bs-select-25" tabindex="-1" aria-multiselectable="true"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner " role="presentation"></ul></div></div></div><div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
```

Note that the label class now doesn't have id = d_assessor4-label so @Jan's code doesn't find it. I reverted back to using the selector from the example above, which deletes everything but the label again, I guess because the label doesn't have an ID? This is what is left.

```
<label class="control-label" for="d_assessor4">Select Repeated Measures for Rick</label>
```

I am confused as to why the code generation changed and how I can target that whole div again.

Comment: Aha, I had to add this to the loop deleting the UI: `removeUI(selector = paste0("label[for~=\'d_assessor",i,"\']"),immediate = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the way Shiny translates the component into HTML. The `<label/>` is outside the `<select/>` tag. So when you use `#d_assessor1` as selector you do not catch the whole thing. You have to go for the surrounding `<div/>`.

```html
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container"> <!-- the div to target -->
  <label class="control-label" id="d_assessor1-label" for="d_assessor1-selectized">Select Repeated Measures for John</label>

  <div> <!-- This is the div your selector catches -->
    <select id="d_assessor1" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" class="selectized shiny-bound-input"></select>
    <div class="selectize-control multi plugin-selectize-plugin-a11y">
        <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="d_assessor1-selectized" style="width: 4px;" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="0djcue83q0">
        </div>
        <div class="selectize-dropdown multi plugin-selectize-plugin-a11y" style="display: none;">
            <div class="selectize-dropdown-content" role="listbox" id="0djcue83q0"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="d_assessor1">{"plugins":["selectize-plugin-a11y"]}</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the code below I used a selector that gets the surrounding div of the label. That may still be improved (because it depends on the current implementation that uses the `select` id and adds "-label"), but it should do the trick.

```r
  observeEvent(c(input$msa_d_UI1,input$msa_d_internal), {
    UI1 <- as.numeric(input$msa_d_UI1)
    do_internal <- input$msa_d_internal
    req(UI1, do_internal)
    choices <- assessors

    # take out those already selected
    fact_selected <- UI1
    temp <- seq_along(choices) #seq(1:length(choices))
    temp <- temp[-fact_selected]
    choices <- choices[temp]
    sel_apps_names <- names(assessors)[UI1]

    num <- length(UI1)

    adds <- seq(1,num)
    for (i in adds){
      #first remove current UI
      removeUI(selector = paste0("div:has(> #d_assessor",i,"-label)"), immediate = TRUE)

      #add new UI
      here <- ifelse(i == 1, "#d_assessor0", paste0("div:has(> #d_assessor",i-1,"-label)"))
      insertUI(
        selector=here,
        where="afterEnd",
        ui=selectInput(inputId = paste0("d_assessor",i),
                       label = paste0("Select Repeated Measures for ", sel_apps_names[i]),
                       multiple=T,
                       choices = choices),
        immediate = TRUE
      )
    }

  })
```

Comment: This helped at first, but please see my edits to the original question if you can help again.